# Why I can't query a subset of data from Datastax DSE 5.0.x Graph without getting allow_scan is disabled error?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

Hi I have disabled scans in my schema.

I know that queries like those wouldn't be allowed:

```
g.V()

g.V().hasLabel("User")
```

> org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: Could
>   not find an index to answer query clause and graph.allow_scan is
>   disabled:

I wonder why even those:

```
g.V().limit(2)

g.V().hasLabel("User").limit(2)
```

cause the same exception to be thrown! This is frustrating since they are bounded queries and they certainly don't cause full cassandra table scans..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's an ongoing discussion about what kind of queries (if any at all) should be allowed with scans disabled. For now the rule is simple: If the initial step is not an index lookup, then it's considered to be a full scan.

It's easy to say that:

```
g.V().hasLabel("user").limit(2)
```

...for example should be allowed, but if that is not considered to be a full scan, then what about these:

```
g.V().hasLabel("user").limit(10)
g.V().hasLabel("user").limit(100)
g.V().hasLabel("user").limit(1000)
g.V().hasLabel("user").limit(10000)
g.V().hasLabel("user").limit(100000)
```

Where do we draw the line? I'm not expecting you to answer this question, just want to show that it's not as easy as it may seem at first.

Comment: I understand that and I expected this answer but people say never run with allow_scan to true in production.. but this is really hard if for example I need to take let's say the last 100 users that entered the system. what should I do..? I thought btw that at least using hasLabel("user") would use an index behind the scenes but now I understand that's a whole cassandra table. Does it make sense to throw an exception in the case of full scan .. That is the question.. there should be way to be notified by a log message and suppress the exception..